# Conversion of Coldfusion Date format to C Sharp format

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to convert a coldfusion code to csharp but with little success.
Cold fusion code goes as below:

```
<CFSET iTimeBefore = #TimeFormat( Now(), 'hh:mm:ss tt' )#>
Some DB Operation here...
<CFSET iTimeBefore = #Caller.iTimeBefore#>
<CFSET iTimeAfter = #TimeFormat( Now(), 'hh:mm:ss tt' )#>
<cfset TimeDiff = #iTimeAfter# - #iTimeBefore#>
<CFSET TimeDiff = TimeDiff*100000>
<CFSET TimeDiff = #NumberFormat(TimeDiff, '99.999')#>
```

Essentially, the code is checkiing for time elapsed  while performing DB operation.
I have tried to use 'TimeSpan' class in C# but it gives current time as follows:

```
TimeSpan dtOprnStartTime1 = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

Output:
20:15:12.9661624
```

Kindly advise.

Comment: Is this a C# question? Then remove the ColdFusion part.

Comment: @Tomalak: This is a C# question. Coldfusion code is to help people identify the operation performed in original code. I am supposed to re-write CopldFusion code in C#.

Comment: First off, the ColdFusion code is bad. Really, you would not do it like that in CF. Secondly, it is distracting. If you just say what you need ("measure a timespan in C#") you're actually helping. If you show an implementation in an obscure language that almost nobody knows, your're *not* helping. ;) For the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateTime before = DateTime.Now;

// Some DB Operation here

TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.Now - before;

Console.Write(elapsed);
```